# send sms using third-party REST service inside a Spring boot application

Tags: spring, rest, spring-boot, spring-rest

i want to send sms to user mobile number using third-party REST service inside a Spring boot application.
API like follow:

`http://cloud.smsindiahub.in/vendorsms/pushsms.aspx?user=abc&password=xyz&msisdn=919898xxxxxx&sid=SenderId&msg=test%20message&fl=0&gwid=2`

`user: Your login username.
password: Your login password.
msisdn: Single mobile number
sid: Approved sender id(Only 6 characters).
msg: Your message content(Minimum 459 characters/3 messages). Note: If you are using template then edit only the dynamic part which is in ##Field##.
fl: if flash message then 1 or else 0
gwid: 2 (its for Transactions route.)
Note: Only 100 mobile numbers are allowed.`

So i want to ask can i do using `RestTemplate` or any other way better in spring boot?
also i want to save response which like below which is josn response:

`{"ErrorCode":"000","ErrorMessage":"Success","JobId":"381a8090-b230-42fa-ac04-157cc2142bfa","MessageData":[{"MobileNumber":"919898xxxxxx ","MessageParts":[{"MessageId": "919898xxxxxx -67e3765cdf034f438a432eacb88d0c14","MessagePartId":1,"MessageText":"test message"}]}]}`

and for REST API username and password saving application.xml is secure?also how to save and access in class.
if any example for the same just send me link.
thanks.

Comment: any one please reply

Answer (score 0):

First, Your API provider should a different authentication method like Auth key as using username and password in RestAPI is not good option.

Now, You can call 3rd party RestAPI url in springboot as below:

```
private static void custom_func()
{
    final String uri = "http://cloud.smsindiahub.in/vendorsms/pushsms.aspx?user=abc&password=xyz&msisdn=919898xxxxxx&sid=SenderId&msg=test%20message&fl=0&gwid=2";

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class);

    System.out.println(result);
}
```